# Group Rows by Column Value

Tags: loops, excel, grouping, vba

In a macro, I would like to group rows that have the same values in the fourth column. There are a finite number of values in that column (so I could potentially write code for each possible value) but it would be stronger to assume infinite values.

My first thought is to create a loop that selects rows with a given value and then use "Selection.Group". I would "Loop Until"  column 1 "IsEmpty".

Not quite sure how to implement this. The following is what I've got, which gives me an error messaage; Method 'Range' of object_"Worksheet" failed"

```
Sub Test()
     Dim Item As Range
     Item = Range(A2, A10)
     If Item.Cells = "a" Then Cell.Select
     Selection.Group
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you try what you have thought to do, and let us know if it works, or if you have questions about how to improve on that method.  You'll probably get better advice if you post your own code first, and then ask for help.

Comment: To group them together, you will have to sort them first.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a recorded macro of the "sorting" part with the sheet declared as DIM:

```
Dim MySheet As Worksheet: Set MySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
MySheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
MySheet.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With MySheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:A10")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Now, about *grouping* the cells.You may declare ranges over each "group" based on it's value, like in named ranges `(Ctrl+F3)`:

```
For i = 1 To MySheet.Rows.Count
    Range_Start = "A" & i 'Store the begining of the range
    If Range("A" & i) <> Range("A" & i - 1) Then
    Range_End = "A" & i 'Store the begining of the range
    MyRange = MySheet.Range(Range_Start & ":" & Range_End)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="range" & ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count + 1, RefersTo:=MyRange
Next i
```

`Although, I think the storing of the Range_Start may need some fine-tunning`

Anyway. The best approach is to use the `Record` feature. Then, Adjust the code by declaring your variables `DIM`(s), and only after write your loops. As based on your question I'm not clear as what you mean by grouping and what you need it for. Cheers!

Comment: If you select a few rows and run a macro with the simple command "Selection.Group" you'll see what I mean. Once rows are groups you can easily hide and unhide them with one click on the lhs. The tricky part of this task is defining what range to group, which I'm working through using "if" statements with offsetting selections within loops                                                                Haven't quite gotten it yet but I'll post my code when I do.